# Default _showConstraints value for the form inputText in views

Tags: playframework-2.0

I don't want to have to define arg '_showConstraints -> false for each of my inputText of my views.

```
@inputText(taskForm("name"), '_showConstraints -> false )
```

How could I do to defaulting this value to false ?

I found some stuff about this arg in ./play/src/main/scala/views/helper/Helpers.scala :

```
def infos(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang): Seq[String] = {
  args.get('_help).map(m => Seq(m.toString)).getOrElse {
    (if (args.get('_showConstraints) match {
      case Some(false) => false
      case _ => true
    }) {
      field.constraints.map(c => play.api.i18n.Messages(c._1, c._2: _*)) ++
        field.format.map(f => play.api.i18n.Messages(f._1, f._2: _*))
    } else Nil)
  }
}
```

I'm totally newbie with scala, how could I do to override this part of code of Helpers.scala in my project ?

(PS: I don't consider editing ./play/src/main/scala/views/helper/Helpers.scala as a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own FieldConstructor (more info here : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers), and specify something like that :

```
@if(elements.args.get('_showConstraints).map{ _ == true}.getOrElse(false)) {
    <pre class="help-block">@elements.infos(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</pre>
}
```

Now constraints will only show if you specify :

```
@helper.inputText(form("name"), '_showConstraints -> true)
```